# rails form_for with Client Side Validation error on load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, postgresql

I am trying to use the CLient Side Validation Gem in Rails.  My forms work find until add the `:validate => true" to my form_for.  Then I get an error telling me the way I have it written is wrong.  I have tried reformatting it like the example and it just throws errors.

**error**

```
Using form_for(:name, @resource) is not supported with ClientSideValidations. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead.
```

**hashtag_controller**

```
def home    
        @leaderboard = Hashtag.leaderboard_history
        @trends_display = Trend.trends_display
        @hash_create = ""
    end
    def create 
        @hash_create = Hashtag.create_hashtag(params[:hashtag])
        Hashlog.create_hashlog(params[:hashtag])
        @random_hashtag_pull = Hashtag.random_hashtags_pull
        @leaderboard = Hashtag.leaderboard_history_current
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to root_path }
            format.js 
        end
    end
```

**hashtag.rb**

```
class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :text, :profile_image_url, :from_user, :created_at, :tweet_id, :hashtag, :from_user_name, :view_count, :wins

  hashtag_regex = /^[A-Za-z\d=#...-]+$/i

  validates :hashtag, :format => { :with => hashtag_regex }, :length => { :within => 2..20 }                    


 class << self

def create_hashtag(hashtag)                #creates new tweetvstweet for inputed hashtag with # for guests
    dash = "#"
    @hashtag_scrubbed = [dash, hashtag].join.downcase
    (User.current_user ? User.current_user.twitter : Twitter).search("%#{@hashtag_scrubbed}", :lang => "en", :count => 100, :result_type => "mixed").results.map do |tweet|
        unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
      create!(
        tweet_id: tweet.id,
        text: tweet.text,
        profile_image_url: tweet.user.profile_image_url,
        from_user: tweet.from_user,
        from_user_name: tweet.user.name, 
        created_at: tweet.created_at,
        hashtag: @hashtag_scrubbed,
        view_count: "0",
        wins: "0"
          ) 
        end  
    end
end



  def random_hashtags_pull                         #pulls 4 random hashtags for a vote first display
    Hashtag.where{ |hashtag| hashtag.hashtag =~ @hashtag_scrubbed}.order{"RANDOM()"}.limit(4).each(&:update_view_count)
  end

  def cast_vote_hashtag(hashtag)                    #pulls 4 random hashtags for a vote continued votes
    Hashtag.where{ |hashtag| hashtag.hashtag =~ @hashtag_scrubbed}.order{"RANDOM()"}.limit(4).each(&:update_view_count)
  end

  def leaderboard_history_current                  #displaying 5 highscore hashtags on the right
    Hashtag.where{ |hashtag| hashtag.hashtag =~ @hashtag_scrubbed}.order{"wins DESC"}.limit(5)  
  end

  def cast_vote(cast_vote)                           #counts number of wins
    Hashtag.increment_counter(:wins, cast_vote)
  end

  def leaderboard_history                            #right side leaderboard history
    Hashtag.order('wins DESC').limit(5)
  end
end

  def update_view_count                                  #updates the number of views
    Hashtag.increment_counter(:view_count, self.id)
    self.view_count += 1 
  end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<div class="span6 votes-middle">
    <%= render 'shared/twitter_search' %>
    </div>

**search form**
<%= form_for(@hash_create, :url => hashtags_path, :validate => true, remote: true)  do |f| %>

                <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                <span class="add-on swag">#</span>
                <%= f.text_field :hashtag,class: "span4 swag_text_field", id:"appendedPrependedInput",  :validate => true, data: {autocomplete_source: autocomplete_index_path} %>

                <%= f.submit "VS!", class: "btn add-on-right swag_button" %>
                <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create a new object for the form

Add @hash_create = HashTag.new in new action and change your form as

```
form_for(@hash_create, :url => hashtags_path, :validate => true, remote: true)
```

Comment: The validation now works, but it passes parameters as `  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1ZxXBeeMogGx4uApJM+1LvmdBv2JdTxdKzndYRYOAAE=", "hashtag"=>{"hashtag"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"VS!"}`so I can no longer use `params[:hashtag]` so the functionality doesn't work.

Comment: Just had to use params[:hashtag][:hashtag]

Comment: If you are using `form_for` it should be required model object. Please refer [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)
we can only access the value of text_field in form_for using model name followed by text_field name like `params[:model_name][:field_name]`.

I understand that you want to access text field value only by params[:hashtag] right?
for that you can use `form_tag`. client_side_validations also support simple form or else you can change text_field to text_field_tag 

Just like
`<% text_field_tag "hashtag", params[:hashtag] %>`